# Cannot implement abstract class from other package

Tags: java, abstract-class

For some reason I seem not to be able to implement an abstract class outside of the package within which it is defined. An abstract class in package1 cannot be implemented in a class in package2. Why is this not legal Java?

```
package com.stackoverflow.abstraction.package1;

abstract public class BaseClass {
    abstract Long foo();
}

package com.stackoverflow.abstraction.package1;

public class Implement1 extends BaseClass {
    @Override
    Long foo() {
        return null;
    }
}


package com.stackoverflow.abstraction.package2;

import com.stackoverflow.abstraction.package1.BaseClass;

/** Compiling this class will output
* - Implement2 is not abstract and does not override abstract method foo() in BaseClass
* - error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
*/

public class Implement2 extends BaseClass {
    @Override
    Long foo() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Running:
OS X 10.6.8
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-415-10M3646)
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-u4-b13-20120301)
Tried both Java versions. Not at the same time, of course :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your two `foo` methods have the default "package" access. Your `Implementation2` class couldn't even *call* the method - so it doesn't make much sense to be able to *override* it.

It's not clear what level of access you *want* them to have, but the simplest approach is probably to make them both public. At the moment, you're saying that only callers in `package1` can call `BaseClass.foo()`, but only callers in `package2` can call `Implement2.foo()`. That clearly doesn't make much sense. Who do you *want* to be able to access the method? If you only want callers within the class or a subclass to be able to call it, then make it `protected` - otherwise make it `public`.

See [section 6.6 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6) (and the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)) for more details of access modifiers. In particular, after going through the various access modifiers:

> Otherwise, we say there is default access, which is permitted only when the access occurs from within the package in which the type is declared.

Comment: You sure are quick to expand your answer. Funny to see how it evolves from a single line :)

Comment: @oligofren: I don't think this particular one was ever a single line, but yes - I start off with the bare bones, then add more context, suggestions, links etc.

Answer (score 14):

That method is package level visibility, so you cant override it at other package.

```
abstract Long foo();
```

> If a method has no modifier (the default, also known as
>   package-private), it is visible only within its own package

If you really need to override it, make it as `protected` instead.

```
protected abstract Long foo();
```

**Info**

- [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)
- [Java Modifier Summary](http://www.javacamp.org/javai/modifier.html)

Comment: Thanks, added some info to clear up your answer. Was not entirely clear as it was, but I got the little bit of info I needed, and hopefully it should make sense to others as well :)

Answer (score 4):

You have four access modificators:
- public - you can use it everywhere
- private - you can use it only inside class
- protected - you can use only inside class and classes which inherit it
- package access (default, without modificator) - you can use it only in package, which the class belong to

In this case you have no modificator, which in general is treated like package access.